# The minimum of two big-O functions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

Suppose we have the following lower and upper bounds for an invariant $\chi(G_N)$, where $G_N$ is a graph on $N$ vertices, $N=f(k,n,m) $ and $N,k,n,m\in \mathbb{N}$:
  $$ \alpha(1-O\left({k}/{n}\right)) \le \chi(G_N) \le \alpha, $$
and
  $$ \alpha(1-O\left({m}/{n}\right)) \le \chi(G_N) \le \alpha. $$
Based on the values of parameters $k,n,m$, either of the lower bounds above can be stronger than the other. How can I represent the lower bounds using one term? Is it mathematically correct to set $ \epsilon = \min\{ O\left({k}/{n}\right),O\left({m}/{n}\right) \}  $ and say $ \alpha(1-\epsilon) \le \chi(G_N) \le \alpha $?

Is it correct to set $ g=\min\{ {m}/{n}, k/n\}$ and say $ \alpha(1-O(g)) \le \chi(G_N) \le \alpha $?

Comment: I think the second option is clearer than the first, and quite reasonable. You might possibly write $\alpha(1-O(\min\{k,m\}/n)) \le \chi(G_N) \le \alpha$ as well.

Comment: Maybe $\alpha(1-O\left({k+m}/{n}\right)) \le \chi(G_N) \le \alpha$?

Comment: @robit, I guess you mean $O((k+m)/n) $. If it is what you mean, then this expression may make the lower bound less strong. It happens, for example, when $k+m=cn$ for some constant $c$.

Comment: Sorry for the typos. I  mean $O((k+m)/n)$. I guess in some cases it is useful even it's less strong.